# google maps api marker custom image error loading

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i have a scenario to check if the marker custom image exists for the given url,if the url return 404 i should create a default svg letter image by considering an email id.
I am able to create a svg image independently and using it as marker icon.I created a function to create a letter image which is working fine.

So here is my question

How do i know that a given url is 404 ?

i) I used Ajax to check if image exists or not synchronously but it is not a
  feasible solution as i have around 500 markers to check the url for ,it is taking long to create markers on the map .

ii) I also used image.onerror() and image.onload() but i could not make this synchronous.

here is the sample snippet how am rendering the marker,i am pasting the ajax code which is working fine but taking long to load

```
var icon = {
     url: markerImageUrl, // url
     size: new google.maps.Size(40, 40),
     origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
     scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(30,30),
     anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
 };

$.ajax({
    url:markerImageUrl,
    type:'HEAD',
    async:false,
    error: function()
    {
        console.log("Error in image url" +i);
        icon.url=prepareLettergravatar(email);//Function which gives me svg url 
    },
    success: function()
    {
        //file exists
    }
});



marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatlng[i],
  map: map,
  icon:icon
});
```

Please suggest me the possible solutions

Thanks

Comment: Could you create all the markers initially using the default marker, then do ajax requests to check them all, and asynchronously change their icons?  That way at least you've got some kind of marker people can see immediately, and they progressively (and hopefully quite quickly) change?

Comment: Hi duncan ,thanks for the comment .I finally had to go with  the common Letter  image for all markers ,but checking the url only on clicking the marker .